# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')

Tags: javascript, express, orm, sequelize.js

so ive tried to create a get one data from a table using findOne function(sequelize) but for some reason it wont define it

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')

im using expressjs with sequelize orm

here is my import

```
const kas = require('../models/').kas;
```

and here is my code section

```
const totalAllKas = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await kas.findOne({
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ]
        })

        console.log(result.total);
        res.json("success");

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'internal server error' });
    }
}
```

i tried to create a new import with the same models yields the same ting
tried to use findAll but still shows the same error

Comment: have you tried console.log(kas) , it could be undefined !

Comment: yeah it was undefined actually,any idea of how to import it properly? i was able to to that  before but all the sudden it was undefined? here is my kas.js on models
```
const { sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = async(sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const kas = sequelize.define("kas", {
        tipe: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },

        total: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },

    })
    return kas;
}```

sorry for the bad code

Comment: there should be an index.js file in your models directory. you should check that. 

normally you should be able to do like:

const { model1, model2 } =require(pathToModelDir)

if you did not mess up the auto gen code for model index, file the above should work !

good luck

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your models (including kas) were not created or defined correctly.

You can create model using sequelize-cli.

> npx sequelize-cli init
>
> npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string,phone:string